# Automorphism and endomorphism of the Toeplitz algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\ H=l^2(\mathbb{Z}_+)$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\ {e_k}$, and $T$ will be right shift operator, t.i. $Te_k=e_{k+1}$. $C^*$ algebra generated by T is a Toeplitz algebra and denote it by $\mathcal{T}$. Let $\alpha$ be an endomorphism of $\mathcal{T}$: 
$\alpha(a)=TaT^*$. It is easy to verify, that $\alpha$ is an endomorphism.Why $\alpha$ does not automorphism?? In my opinion, $\alpha(a)$ is a surjective, but it doesnot injective.  And what are the elements of $Aut(\mathcal{T}$.)??
Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $T^{\star}e_{1}=0$. So $\alpha(a)e_{1}=0$ for all $a$.